# I'm getting null while passing data from one viewController to another in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I try to set a NSString property of a second view controller when a button is clicked from one view controller

```
CommentsViewController *commentViewController =  [[CommentsViewController alloc] init];

STPopupController *commentPopupController = [[STPopupController alloc] initWithRootViewController:commentViewController];
commentPopupController.containerView.layer.cornerRadius = 4;

commentViewController.streamID = trackID;
commentViewController.radioID = radioID;


[commentPopupController presentInViewController:self];
```

But when the view controller shows as popup, those string values are null. what are my getting wrong?

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *streamID;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *radioID;
```

Is it that the view controller is initiated twice or what, i couldn't locate where the problem is.
this is the init method of the comment view controller

```
- (instancetype)init {
if (self == [super init]) {
    self.title = @"Comments";
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    self.contentSizeInPopup = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width - 50 , self.view.frame.size.height - 150);
    // self.landscapeContentSizeInPopup = CGSizeMake(400, 200);
}
return self;
```

}

Comment: why do you set commentViewController as rootViewController here?

Comment: Why did not use the code in appdelegate didFininishLaunchWithOptions?

Comment: it's another section of the app in another storyboard

Comment: Do you use two storyboards?

Comment: one, but the startup section of the app was done by someone else using xib files

Comment: If you use xib, use xib only and If you use stroyboard use storyboard only because you will be confuse.

Comment: Did you write coding in didFinishLauchingWithOptions?

Comment: - (instancetype)init is called twice. In second call, it will set your value to (null).

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to do is to check with debugger. Maybe the values you pass are null?

Put breakpoints where you think the problem is.

Comment: the values i passed aren't null, i've checked

Answer (score 0):

If you have to pass the values to the view controller which is not present in the navigation stack, then if you are pushing view controller which is on storyboard then you must create instance of view controller as

```
STPopupController *objViewController = [Self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"identifier"];
```

And pass values like

```
 objViewController.streamID = trackID;
 objViewController.radioID = radioID;
```

And if you are using xib then use following

```
SecondViewController *tempView = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil]
```

Correct me if there is any mistake in my code as i'm posting answere from my phone.

Answer (score 0):

Without any indication where you are accessing `streamID` or `radioID` in your `CommentsViewController` it's hard to say why they are nil.

It could be that `STPopupController` is accessing the view property on your `CommentsViewController` in its init method. This will cause your `viewDidLoad` method to be called, before you actually assign any values to the properties.

Easiest fix in this case would be to assign the values before you create the popup controller.

```
// I would recommend using initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil here, even if
// you create the view in code.
CommentsViewController *commentViewController = [[CommentsViewController alloc] init];

// assign before creating STPopupController
commentViewController.streamID = trackID;
commentViewController.radioID = radioID;

STPopupController *commentPopupController = [[STPopupController alloc] initWithRootViewController:commentViewController];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely due to failed initialization:

```
- (instancetype)init {
if (self == [super init]) {
```

Note the `==`

It should be:

```
- (instancetype)init {
if (self = [super init]) {
```

Assignment, not equality.

Comment: Note to those attempting to edit. I intentionally formatted my response as I did to mirror the author's original code. As well, I wanted to keep it as brief as possible (yet maintain a little bit of context) to highlight the problematic part of code.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your target controller:

```
CommentsViewController *commentViewController =  [[CommentsViewController alloc] init];
```

and then, pass datas:

```
commentViewController.streamID = trackID;
commentViewController.radioID = radioID;
```

Finally, push STPopupController by:

```
[self.popupController pushViewController:commentViewController animated:YES];
```

**Note:** `popupController` is a property of `STPopupController` that comes with `#import <STPopup/STPopup.h>`